# How do I create a Python class in C?

Tags: python, c

I have a legacy C library that creates a tree of objects. I would like to convert the tree into a pre-existing Python class. How do I create the PyObject for that class?

Answer (score 4):

[Cython](http://www.cython.org/) is capable of doing this.  It's a semi-fork of Pyrex, and it can wrap existing data structures and expose them to Python.  In fact, this is one of the [sections in the user guide](http://docs.cython.org/docs/external_C_code.html).  Cython is relatively easy to use, and it includes an HTML-output format that shows all the generated code as well as highlighted hot spots where optimization could be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at generating your Python bindings by using a tool such as [pybindgen](https://launchpad.net/pybindgen/).  These guys are trying to make a superior binding generator, they talk about the shortcomings of other tools (e.g. SWIG) on their front page.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using [Robin](http://robin.python-hosting.com/) in these scenarios.